# Does Joomla! follow MVC Architecture?

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, content-management-system

A lot of [Joomla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla) Documentation talks about MVC, i'm just wondering if [Joomla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla) follows MVC and how strictly it does so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

component development in joomla strickly follows MVC framework. Check it http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1